# This data graph is missing a valid configuration. unreachable

Tags: apollo

when I ran the gateway server it shows this error "This data graph is missing a valid configuration. unreachable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I solved it by trying different versions of Apollo federation & gateway ( the latest version didn't work for me )

Comment: "@apollo/federation": "^0.17.0"
 "@apollo/gateway": "^0.21.0",
 "apollo-server": "^2.18.2",

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by upgrading apollo gateway to the latest version

Comment: didnt work..same problem even with 0.22.0

Comment: yeah, same for me. 0.22.0 doesn't work neither.